# How to wait for a function to complete before moving to next in loop in Android using Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator

So I have an app which preloads graphics from an API.

I firstly grab all of the data I need from my onboard DB, loop through it and send the user off to a function to download the image, resize it etc.

on iOS this seems to work great, however on Android it keeps falling over.

I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing this, that won't crash the app.

Is there a way I can wait for the `getMarker()` function to complete before my loop (from the `getMapMarkers()` function) fires another request to it?

Here is my code snippet for that part of my app. The function `getMarker()` does the processing of the image and resizing.

```
function getMarker(url, filename) {

    var mapMarker = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'map_marker_icons', filename);

    // now we need to download the map marker and save it into our device 
    var getMarker = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        timeout: 30000
    });

    getMarker.onload = function() {

        // if the file loads, then write to the filesystem
        if (getMarker.status == 200) {

                var image = this.responseData;
                // resize to 75 pixel marker
                var resizedImage = image.imageAsResized(75, 75);
                mapMarker.write(resizedImage);

                //I ALWAYS NULL ANY PROXIES CREATED SO THAT IT CAN BE RELEASED
                image = null;
                resizedImage = null;
                mapMarker = null;


        } else {
            Ti.API.info("Image not loaded");
        }


        //getMarker = null;


    };

    getMarker.onerror = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('XHR Error ' + e.error);
        //alert('markers data error');
    };

    getMarker.ondatastream = function(e) {


        if (e.progress == 1) {
            Ti.API.info(filename + ' Download Complete');

        }
    };

    // open the client
    getMarker.open('GET', url);

    // send the data
    getMarker.send();

}

function getMapMarkers() {
    // get the species list back
    var db = Ti.Database.open('myDB');
    var getSpeciesImages = db.execute('SELECT speciesiconfilename, speciesmapiconurl FROM species where speciesiconfilename <> ""');

    // YOU ONLY NEED TO DO THIS ONCE SO DO IT OUTSIDE THE LOOP
    var imgDir = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'map_marker_icons');

    // if the directory doesn't exist, then we need to create it
    if (!imgDir.exists()) {
        // If the directory doesn't exist, make it
        imgDir.createDirectory();
    };

    // start the loop
    while (getSpeciesImages.isValidRow()) {
        var filename = getSpeciesImages.fieldByName('speciesiconfilename');
        var url = getSpeciesImages.fieldByName('speciesmapiconurl');

        getMarker(url, filename);

        getSpeciesImages.next();

    } // end the loop

    getSpeciesImages.close();


    // close the database
    db.close();

    // get the exhibit markers next
    getExhibitMapMarkers();
};
```

Anyone able to help? It's driving me crazy!

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more js question than titanium. I prefer to use Q library (https://github.com/kriskowal/q) for such things.

```
function getMarker(url, filename) {
    return function() {
        var defered = Q.defer();

        ...
        var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
            timeout: 30000
        });

        xhr.onload = function() {
            ...
            defered.resolve();
        };

        xhr.onerror = function(e) {
            ...
            defered.resolve(); // or defered.reject() if you want stop after first error
        }
        ...
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();

        return defered.promise;
    };
}

function getMapMarkers() {
    ...
    var imageRequests = [];

    while(getSpeciesImages.isValidRow()) {
        ...
        imageRequests.push(getMarker(url, filename));
        getSpeciesImages.next();
    }

    imageRequests.reduce(Q.when, Q(true))
    .then(function() {
        Ti.API.info('all loaded');
    });
    ...
};
```

And don't name http client variable same as getMarker() function!